# Order & Orderby Parameters

Tags: parameter

I am trying to figure out what the orderby parameter is for "newest" post author.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

I want to order users by authors who posted the newest posts (post date).

What would be the parameter for that?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the best way to do that would be a custom `WP_Query()` to get the necessary post IDs you want, then loop through those and get the author for each post ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi for me fast solution is to use custom query

for eg.

```
$sql="SELECT
    `wp_users`.`ID`
    , `wp_users`.`user_login`
    , `wp_users`.`user_pass`
    , `wp_users`.`user_nicename`
    , `wp_users`.`user_email`
    , `wp_users`.`user_url`
    , `wp_users`.`user_registered`
    , `wp_users`.`user_activation_key`
    , `wp_users`.`user_status`
    , `wp_users`.`display_name`
    , `wp_posts`.`post_date`
FROM
    `wp_users`
    LEFT JOIN `wp_posts` 
        ON (`wp_users`.`ID` = `wp_posts`.`post_author`)
GROUP BY `wp_users`.`ID`
ORDER BY `wp_posts`.`post_date` DESC;";

global $wpdb;
$results=$wpdb->get_results($sql);
foreach($results as $result) {
    echo $result->ID; //and so on
}
```

Comment: I think you'll find the OP is referring to `WP_User_Query`, not `WP_Query`. See the link in the question